# Get file path, use as a variable in a keystroke (applescript)

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to write a script that will get the selected file's path and type it into terminal for me. I'm new to scripting so this is all I have so far - the mistakes will be nice and obvious!

**set filepath to (currently selected file's path, or drag-and-dropped file...?)**

**activate application "Terminal"**

**tell application "System Events" to keystroke "./aerender -project " + "'$filepath'"**

**tell application "System Events" to keystroke return****

I know that's totally wrong but hopefully it give the idea of what I'm trying to do.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can script Terminal directly... no need for UI scripting.

```
tell application "Finder" to set filePath to POSIX path of file (selection as string)
set filePath to quoted form of filePath
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    set currentTab to do script ("./aerender -project " & filePath)
end tell
```

Comment: That's great, thank you. The reason I am using Applescript is because I want to drag and drop a project file onto an applescript Application, and have it render that file in Terminal (that's the 'aerender' command). Two problems: One, the way the script is currently, it puts single quotes around the file path in the Terminal. And two, I just saved your script as an application, and discovered I can't drag and drop anything onto it...!  Any suggestions? Thank you, by the way!

Comment: PS - I just figured out how to get rid of the single quotes - delete the second line. So it works perfectly... Except I can't drop a file onto the Applescript App... ?

Comment: Aha! Figured a work-around, at least. I put an alias of the compiled script onto the dock. Then I select the project file, and then click on the dock icon, and it works. Seems a bit jury-rigged, though...

Comment: You can also put the script in a Script Droplet. If the answer is helping, please do 'accept' the answer.